# jlink created runtime hangs on windows when add-options is used

Tags: java, jlink

When I create a runtime using

```
C:\oracle\jdk-11.0.15\bin\jlink --add-modules ALL-MODULE-PATH --output jre --strip-debug --no-man-pages --no-header-files --compress=2 --module-path "C:\oracle\jdk-11.0.15\jmods" --output compressedrt --add-options="-Xmx64m"
```

and try to execute

```
compressedrt\bin\java.exe -version
```

it simply hangs

It only happens when `add-options` option is used

Newer versions of JDK create a working runtime

```
C:\oracle\jdk-17.0.3.1\bin\jlink --add-modules ALL-MODULE-PATH --output jre --strip-debug --no-man-pages --no-header-files --compress=2 --module-path "C:\oracle\jdk-17.0.3.1\jmods" --output compressedrt --add-options="-Xmx64m"
```

So, I guess, the issue was fixed but not backported?
Unfortunately I could find a related issue in JBS

Answer (score 0):

The issue got confirmed in JBS https://bugs.openjdk.org/browse/JDK-8288172